# Google translate API POST 11second delay?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

EDIT: 11.5 seconds for 28 messages

Single requests work fine. This code below takes 11 seconds, measured using postman setting route in API to access.

Am I doing something wrong? I feel as though it shouldn't take 11 seconds even without cache.

```
$xs = ChatMessage::where('chat_room_id','=',$roomId)
->with('user')
->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
->get();



    foreach($xs as $r){
            
        $translate = new TranslateClient([
            'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        ]);
        
        $result = $translate->translate($r->message_english, [
            'target' =>'es',
            'source' => 'en',
        ]);
        
        $r->message = $result['text'];
    }

return $xs;
```

Comment: How many messages are there, and how long is each one? If it's 11 seconds to translate a single short message, that does seem too long. If you've got 1000 messages that you're translating, then 11 seconds sounds much more reasonable. (I don't know the PHP client library, but I'd *expect* it to be a better idea to just create a single client though...)

Comment: @JonSkeet 11.5 seconds for 28 messages under 10 words each, mostly single words

Comment: @JonSkeet yes Idk why the client was in the loop, now its 5 seconds can it get lower?

Comment: Well you could issue the requests in parallel. 28 requests in 5 seconds seems pretty reasonable though - a sub-200ms average response time doesn't feel particularly bad...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to use it in a live chat application, do you have any tips? I dont want the user waiting there for ages haha

Comment: That's really too broad a question for Stack Overflow, and not what comment threads are designed for anyway. I've suggested that you could issue requests in parallel - or you may find that there's a batch translation function. (There would be in C#; as I say, I don't know the PHP library.)

Comment: Ah yes: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.116.0/translate/v2/translateclient?method=translateBatch

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you know how to issue the requests in parallel in PHP? Without using the batch function, as I need to translate a search query into multiple target languages, which isn't supported very well in the API unless I use the v3 API and store the results as files in Google Cloud it would seem based on the examples I found, although maybe there are more options I haven't found.

Comment: @KevinWheeler: No, I don't know I'm afraid. (I have basically no PHP experience.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can easily speed the process by just moving the client out of the for each loop. You are creating a client each time you iterate. That's not optimal. You should be able to reuse the client per translate call. That should speed your translation process. You can find samples of this usage in the official [github client project](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-translate)

Here is a pseudo code sample:

```
client = new TranslateClient()

foreach(message in messages)
   result = client.translate(message)
   print(result)
```

Also, how long is your translated text? You should pass the whole text to be translated into a single call (as long as the supported library allows) So you also reduce the calls done to the API.

If you still have issues you can go by using multiple request in parallel as mentioned in the comments.

Some useful links about this:

- [PHP Documentation Overview](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/python)
- [Translate Client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.116.0/translate/v2/translateclient)

Comment: Yes it is still slow but for the sake of this question this sufficiently answers it.